# Which methods are available for NMinimize?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, options, optional-arguments

I can't find in the documentation the list of methods available to `NMinimize[]`. Is there a way to get this?
The NMinimize page in Documentation Center mentions only `Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"`.

Comment: If you click on "Details and Options" you'll see the whole list.

Comment: Indeed, the last bullet of that sections reads: *Possible settings for the Method option include "NelderMead", "DifferentialEvolution", "SimulatedAnnealing", and "RandomSearch".* I note that it uses the tantalizing words "possible" and "includes", suggesting there might be many more settings.

Comment: Yes, it is not very clear. I have also found on the page tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationGlobalNumerical the following line: NMinimize and NMaximize have several optimization methods available: Automatic, "DifferentialEvolution", "NelderMead", "RandomSearch", and "SimulatedAnnealing". I assumed there could be more methods available.

Comment: You should read these tutorials [Numerical Nonlinear Global Optimization](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationGlobalNumerical.html#217856200) and [Numerical Nonlinear Global Optimization Examples](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NumericalNonlinearGlobalOptimizationExamples.html#202578656).

Comment: @b.gatessucks you can post your comment as an answer if you want and I'll accept it.

Comment: Not sure if we shouldn't close this question as it only involved a simple manual lookup.

Comment: I would close it.

Comment: An other question would be: Is it possible to use something like `foo::Method` in order to know the different methods available?

Comment: Voting to reopen. Evidently the docs aren't enough for this one

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The complete list of possible methods is given by `` Optimization`NMinimizeDump`$Methods ``:

```
Optimization`NMinimizeDump`$Methods
 (* -> {Automatic, DifferentialEvolution, NelderMead, 
        SimulatedAnnealing, RandomSearch, NonlinearInteriorPoint} *)
```

As you can see, there is one undocumented method: `NonlinearInteriorPoint`. The probable reason for its being undocumented is that by itself it is not very effective as a global minimizer, so it is used instead as a postprocessing step for the other methods in order to ensure that constraints are properly enforced.