# Solving a Nonlinear Optimization using Primal-Dual Interior point method

Tags: mathematical-optimization, nonlinear

I want to solve an optimization problem using the Primal-Dual Interior Point Method. Although *Mathematica* gives the result directly when I use the command [`NMinimize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMinimize.html), I want to get the Newton's iteration values for different barrier parameters.

Is there any way to solve the optimization problem in *Mathematica* using Primal-Dual Interior Point method?

Comment: `Method -> "NonlinearInteriorPoint"`

Comment: @OleksandrR.,Undocumented? `NMinimize`  Docs: Possible settings for the Method option include "NelderMead", "DifferentialEvolution", "SimulatedAnnealing", and "RandomSearch".

Comment: @rhermans yes, undocumented. See [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35493/which-methods-are-available-for-nminimize).

Comment: @rhermans, if you want to see options: ``Options[NMinimize`NonlinearInteriorPoint]``. I believe this is exactly the same method used by `FindMinimum[]` for constrained optimization.

Comment: @OleksandrR. thanks. but I still cant use it. I tried it as : `Method -> "NonlinearInteriorPoint"
NonlinearInteriorPoint [{x - 2*y, 1 + x - y^2 >= 0, y >= 0}, {x, y}]`      but it does not work.

Comment: I am not surprised. It is a method option of `NMinimize`, as explained in the linked thread and alluded to in the other comments.

Comment: Have you tried `FindMinimum`? I think it will have to use this method for all constrained nonlinear and nonquadratic optimization problems.