# Possible bug in NMaximize function?

Tags: bugs, mathematical-optimization

**Bug introduced in 12.0. Fixed in 13.2 or earlier**

---

In `12.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 6, 2019)` writing:

```
Maximize[{Sqrt[1 - x^2], -1 <= x <= 1}, x]
Minimize[{Sqrt[1 - x^2], -1 <= x <= 1}, x]
NMinimize[{Sqrt[1 - x^2], -1 <= x <= 1}, x]
```

the following outputs are obtained immediately:

> {1, {x -> 0}}
>
> {0, {x -> -1}}
>
> {0., {x -> -1.}}

while writing:

```
NMaximize[{Sqrt[1 - x^2], -1 <= x <= 1}, x]
```

the software enters an *infinite loop* without giving any warning.

Am I missing something or is something wrong?

---

**EDIT**: through the email address *support@wolfram.com* I contacted *Wolfram Technical Support* who in less than eight hours have confirmed that it is a bug and have already proceeded to report to their developers.

Comment: Very weird. This also happens to me. MacOS 10.15.1 and MMA V12.0. Interestingly, if you add `StepMonitor :> Print[x]`, it never prints anything. It seems like it's unable to even take a single step. However, if you specify *any* `Method` (other than `Automatic` I suppose) it seems to start working. I wonder if it can't decide which `Method` to use on this problem? Using `NMinimize[{-Sqrt[1 - x^2],...]` also fails. Specifying a search interval, `MaxIterations`, or `PrecisionGoal` don't seem to help. Definitely seems like a bug to me.

Comment: @MassDefect Even weirder: `Automatic` works fine too! Your further evidence with `Print` also seems to indicate that the process gets stuck early, and never gets to any calculations when no method is included.

Comment: One workaround is to use `Surd` instead of `Sqrt`, i.e., `NMaximize[{Surd[1 - x^2, 2], -1 <= x <= 1}, x]`

Comment: It should be noticed that the notation -1 <= x <= 1 is not mathematically correct because <= is a binary relation. I don't understand the economy of two symbols in comparison with -1 <= x &&x<=1.

Comment: Just to mention that in Mma 11.2 NMaximize seems to work ok.

Comment: @user64494: Well, that notation is used everywhere in the mathematical community. It is certainly considered "correct" by the vast majority of mathematical students, teachers, and researchers. Out of curiosity, would you also object against something like `f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2 + 6x + 9 = (x+3)^2 + y^2 >= 0 for all x and y`? This kind of syntax is somewhat uncommon in programming languages (because there these symbols are typically binary operators returning booleans), but that's another story.

Comment: Seems to have been fixed in MMA 12.1

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is an extended comment rather than an answer, but it would have been unwieldy in a comment box.

I was able to reproduce the problem you describe on Windows 10 / MMA 12. I also noticed that specifying any method option seems to eliminate the problem. Below is a list of [the methods available to `NMinimize`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/35497/27951) on my system; I assumed that the same are available to `NMaximize` as well and tried them explicitly:

```
NMaximize[{Sqrt[1 - x^2], -1 <= x <= 1}, x, Method -> #]& /@ {"Automatic", 
   "DifferentialEvolution", "MeshSearch", "NelderMead", "SimulatedAnnealing", 
   "RandomSearch", "NonlinearInteriorPoint"}
```

All returned a reasonable answer *with no delay*. I am suspecting that some pre-processing or method selection routine within `NMaximize` may be at fault, since a call with `Method -> Automatic` fails, but specifying any method (weirdly enough, even `"Automatic"` as a string), works fine.

Comment: On my system `Method -> Automatic` does not work, but `Method -> "Automatic"` does work.

Comment: @MassDefect Good observation! Most clues point to a flaw in the method selection routine then. Added your point in the answer.

Answer (score 19):

In V12, WRI introduced new [convex optimization solvers](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ConvexOptimization.html).  `NMiminize` was updated to automatically choose one when appropriate.
But in this case, it seems to enter an infinite loop.  Please report it to WRI.

You can turn off convex minimization as follows:

```
Block[{Optimization`UseConvexMinimize = False &},
 NMaximize[{Sqrt[1 - x^2], -1 <= x <= 1}, x]
 ]
(*  {1., {x -> 1.01852*10^-9}}  *)
```

The offending function is a preprocessor, `` Optimization`TransformProblem ``. If we disable this to just return the first argument (which is an optimization problem object), the optimization is completed successfully:

```
Block[{Optimization`TransformProblem = # &},
 NMaximize[{Sqrt[1 - x^2], -1 <= x <= 1}, x]
 ]
(*  {1., {x -> 1.01852*10^-9}}  *)
```

One might figure this out from the following trace (`NMaximize[f,..]` calls `NMinimize[-f,..]` in effect):

```
Trace[
 TimeConstrained[
  NMinimize[{-Sqrt[1 - x^2], -1 <= x <= 1}, x],
  0.001],
 TraceInternal -> True]
```

If you select the final evaluation chain, which ends with a long repeated sequence of `{Sign[-1],-1},{1/(1/2),2},{Sign[-1],-1}`, it leads you back to `` Optimization`TransformProblem ``.

Comment: @TeM I went to the Wolfram Tech Conference and attended the presentation on convex optimization. In other words, I was lucky. One could view all the WTC presentations online. I'm not sure that would keep one completely up-to-date, but they would probably present the more important advances over the past year. It's a lot of work to do. So I'd rather ask a question on SE and hope someone here had the relevant info. Relying on others to help you is not a bad way to keep up with something as large and complicated and continually evolving like Mathematica.

Comment: The bug was reported in house several months back. As best I can tell, it is fixed for the next release.

Comment: Another way to avoid the convex solver: `Method -> Except["Convex"]`